# Graph Generation in flex

Tags: apache-flex, graph

I need to generate a graph using the following XML in FLEX.

[Bindable] 
public var stockDataAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [
  {date: "2010, 4, 27", close: 41.71},
  {date: "2010, 4, 28", close: 42.21},
  {date: "2010, 5, 2", close: 42.71},
  {date: "2010, 5, 3", close: 42.99},
  {date: "2010, 5, 4", close: 44} ]);

..............
< mx:horizontalAxis >
  < mx:DateTimeAxis dataUnits="days" displayLocalTime="true" parseFunction="myParseFunction" / >
  < /mx:horizontalAxis>

But this displays the graph from 2010/4/27 till 2010/5/4 including 2010/4/29, 2010/4/30 and 2010/5/1. I require the graph to display only the points in XML and exclude remaining thought it lies in between since it contains no data. How this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider tracing lines between the XML points, instead of displaying points.

See `Canvas.lineTo(x,y)` for more.